# If Statement Not Executed in AutocompleteTextView

Tags: android-studio, autocompletetextview

I'm new to Android Studio and currently working on my first app. Thanks to numerous examples on here i have managed to catch up on the basics very quickly. I now have a problem with my autocompletetextview, i want to get the text selected then use it in a if statement to determine what is shown on the "results" textview. The if statement works fine but only for the "else" part and i can't figure out where i went wrong.

I have commented out the onItemClickListener because the "testfoodph" method does the same.

Here is the activity code:

```
public class phTester extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Intent intent = getIntent();

```
AutoCompleteTextView text;
MultiAutoCompleteTextView text1;
TextView results;
String foodies;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ph_tester);

    String[] foods = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.foodlist);

    text=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,foods);

    text.setAdapter(adapter);
    text.setThreshold(1);

    results=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.phResults);
    foodies = text.getText().toString();

    text.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //if (foodies.equalsIgnoreCase("Mango")) {
                //results.setText(getString(R.string.phAlk));
            }
            //else {
                //results.setText(getString(R.string.Error));
            //}
        //}
    });



}
public void TestFoodPH(View view) {
    if (foodies.equalsIgnoreCase("Mango")) {
        results.setText(getString(R.string.phAlk));
    }
    else {
        results.setText(getString(R.string.Error));
    }
}
```

Comment: to get selected item you can call: parent.getItemAtPosition(position); on your onItemClick method inside OnItemClickListner or you can simply query your list of autocomplete data by position which you have in onIteClick

Comment: Thank you Rafal, may you elaborate further, say with an example on how i can implement in inside TestFoodPH method?

Comment: @Rafal forgot to mention you in the reply above, thank you for your help, i managed to work my way around using your suggestion.